# How do I create a live-reload development environment in docker? (NodeJS, Redis & Vue)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I've been attempting to create a docker development environment on my windows machine. The structure of my application is an express/node backend, a vue-cli generated client and a redis-server for caching.

I managed to get the project running, however the final piece I'm struggling with is hot reloading. I've installed nodemon as a dependency and added a script to the package.json file. Whenever I make a change to my server, I'd like the project to restart and show the new updates. This is my current setup. From what I've read it's something to do with volumes (I'm very new to docker).

API/Server Dir Structure

```
backend
- server.js (express server)
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- Models
- ect...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web-container
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build: . 
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    links: 
      - redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis-container
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Important:

When adding the volumes field on the web service, the following error is thrown

```
web-container | > projectname@1.0.0 start /app
web-container | > nodemon server.js --trace-warnings
web-container |
web-container | sh: 1: nodemon: not found
web-container | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
web-container | npm ERR! syscall spawn
web-container | npm ERR! file sh
web-container | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
web-container | npm ERR! projectname@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js --trace-warnings`
web-container | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
web-container | npm ERR!
web-container | npm ERR! Failed at the projectname@1.0.0 start script.
web-container | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging o                                   utput above.
web-container | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
web-container |
web-container | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
web-container | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-23T18_42_42_900Z-debug.log
```

If I remove the volumes field from the service, it runs smoothly and as intended, however I can't begin to approach the hot reloading.

Comment: nodemon starts up if you remove the volume?  I'm surprised. It seems like nodemon is simply just not on your path:  sh: 1: nodemon: not found.

Comment: Can you run Node directly on the host, pointing at a Redis instance in Docker?  That would get you the benefits of using Docker for a disposable local database, but avoids the difficulties of trying to use it for a live development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just that nodemon is not on your executable path. npm install isn't going to do that for you.

There are many ways to fix this, but the simplest would be to just install nodemon globally in the container:

```
RUN npm install -g nodemon --no-optional
```

Comment: Okay so adding that is now causing the following error:
"Can not find module sticky-session"

Which happens which I haven't installed the packages in package.json.
Why is this happening. I've specified in the Dockerfile to the run npm install.

Comment: What does your docker file say when you hit the npm install strophe?  Is sticky-session in your package.json?  bash into the container to see what's going on.

Comment: Just a moment, let me take a look.

Comment: I've managed to get everything running. Nodemon is also running, but not reloading whenever I make a change.